# OPi Zero - update

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, armbian

I’ve been watching my Orange Pi Zero update since yesterday and I’m starting to worry there’s something wrong going on..
It doesn’t appear to be stuck, I can ssh into it and it seems to be working fine (a tad slowly perhaps, but still).
If I run `top` the process `cc1` is working at 99% cpu, but the update process has been stuck on the following lines for literally 24h now:

```
Setting up linux-headers-sun8i (5.35)
Compiling headers - please wait...
```

Should I just keep waiting?
Any chance I can force the process to use all cpu cores rather than just one?

UPDATE
So I’m giving up hope now that it’s about 4 days and 8 hours.

Comment: are you compiling a kernel in Orange Pi?

Comment: I ran apt-get update and upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Some upgrades can trigger kernel compilations with such "esoteric" hardware and setups.

The Opi Zero might be too limited for that; either you wait the operation to finish, or download a new version image were those updates are already applied.

Be aware such frequent operations will do wear and tear to your SD card.

IMO, this is the achilles heel of such cheap iOT devices. The OS versions often are not that well designed/maintained, or not specific to the device and doing the required security update/upgrades can often led to some surprises.  I would add however that the ArmBian guys have been doing a good, volunteer job running it in such many devices.

I also have an R1 with Armbian with an hard disk and upgrading the kernel was most of the time a traumatic operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I guess I’ll do that from now on. Would `qemu`ing the os on my pc and run the update there work?

Comment: you will be  be able to cross-compile things in your linux. Do not have an idea about the feasibility of doing qemu though.